# why 'functools.reduce' and 'itertools.chain.from_itertools' had different computation time when nested list merged

Tags: python, python-3.x, reduce, python-itertools, functools

sometimes you should have nested merge to merged list(it is similar to `np.flatten()` ). 
when the list of list is given like below, and you should flatten it

```
a = [[j for j in range(0, 10)] for i in range(0, 10000)]
```

you have two kinds of solution to solve it. `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `functools.reduce`.

```
%timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
%timeit reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, a)
```

do you think which one is faster and how much faster than other thing?

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` is 1000 times faster or more(when the length of the list is bigger).

If somebody knows why this thing happen, please let me know.

always thx for you support and help.

Comment: While we’re at it, do you actually need a list rather than just an iterator in the first place? If you’re only going to step through it one time, you can save a little time and a lot of memory—and also “pipeline” the time in with the rest of your code instead of doing it all upfront before anything can get started—by just using the `chain` iterator as-is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because list concatenation, i.e. using `+`, is an O(N) operation. When you do that to incrementally build a list of size N, it becomes O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Instead, using `chain.from_iterable` will simply iterate over all N items in the final list, using the `list` type constructor, which will have linear performance.

This is why you shouldn't use `sum` to flatten a list (note, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,...)` is simply `sum`).

Note, the *idiomatic* way to flatten a nested list like this is to use a list comprehension:

```
[x for sub in a for x in sub]
```

This is such an anti-pattern, the `sum` method prevents you doing it with `str` objects:

```
>>> sum(['here', 'is', 'some', 'strings'], '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]
```

Note, your `reduce`/`sum` approach is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for sub in a:
    result = result + sub
```

Which demonstrates the expensive `+` in the loop quite clearly. Note, the following naive approach actually has O(N) behavior instead of O(N<sup>2</sup>):

```
result = []
for sub in a:
    result += sub
```

That is because `my_list += something` is equivalent to `my_list.extend(something)`, and `.extend` (along with `.append`) have amortized constant-time behavior, so overall, it will be O(N).

Comment: thx. idiomatic way you mentioned is better way to solve it. and more explanation about computation is so helpful to me. thx.

Comment: Also, `reduce` with a lambda is even slower than `sum` because it has to do a Python function call each time through the inner loop, in addition to the C method call. In this case it probably doesn’t matter much because the C method call is doing so much work with all that concatenation of copies, but in general (when they’re not both a terrible idea), `sum` is faster. As well as being more readable, shorter, and harder to get wrong.